# Correcting Logic For MySQL Spatial Query

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, join, procedure

My main objective here is to create a **PROCEDURE** in MySQL to query for locations based upon the latitude and longitude being passed. The query grabs the id, latitude, and longitude of the locations within a specific radius of what is passed to the **PROCEDURE**. I am also trying to add a **JOIN** to query the "*photos*" table for photos of each location.

The query partially works. It needs to return all of the locations without doubles, and all of the photos in a string.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(photos.pid, CHAR(8))) AS photo
```

With the addition of this chunk of code, the query returns only 1 result, and concatenates all of the photo id's into one field even if it is not associated with that location. If I remove this chunk of code, it returns 1 of every location, but will double the result for whichever location has 1 or more photos associated with it, so the photos field needs to be concatenated, but I am not properly doing this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GEODIST`( IN userid int, IN dist int, IN olat float, IN olon float ) DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA

BEGIN
DECLARE mylon DOUBLE;
DECLARE mylat DOUBLE;
DECLARE lon1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lon2 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat1 FLOAT;
DECLARE lat2 FLOAT;

SET mylon = olon;
SET mylat = olat;
SET lon1 = mylon - dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lon2 = mylon + dist / abs( cos( radians( mylat ) ) * 69 );
SET lat1 = mylat - ( dist / 69 );
SET lat2 = mylat + ( dist / 69 );

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(photos.pid, CHAR(8))) AS photo, destination.id, 
destination.latitude, destination.longitude,
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -destination.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
+COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(destination.latitude * pi()/180)
*POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -destination.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))
AS distance FROM locations destination CROSS JOIN locations origin LEFT JOIN photos ON photos.lid = destination.id WHERE origin.id = userid
AND destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2 AND destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2 
HAVING distance < dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50;
END
```

Comment: You should group them on destination id, and add distinct.

Comment: Where am I adding GROUP BY destination.id, I can't seem to find the correct spot, I keep throwing errors when trying to GROUP BY, I will also add distinct, but there is something going on with GROUP_CONCAT because when I add GROUP_CONCAT it is only returning 1 result with all of the photo id's lumped into a string in one field even if they are not associated with one another. Should I add GROUP BY while keeping GROUP_CONCAT, or can you specify? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure as I don't use GROUP_CONCAT enough, why don't you just pull out the distinct rows and then group them, Give me few minutes I'll put an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

I image it should go like this but I have no way to test it.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT( CONVERT( DISTINCT( photos.pid ), CHAR(8) ) ) ) AS photo,
    destination.id, 
    destination.latitude,
    destination.longitude,
    3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((origin.latitude -destination.latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
        +COS(origin.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(destination.latitude * pi()/180)
        *POWER(SIN((origin.longitude -destination.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))
    AS distance
FROM
    locations destination
CROSS JOIN
    locations origin
LEFT JOIN
    photos ON photos.lid = destination.id
WHERE
    origin.id = userid
    AND
    destination.longitude BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2
    AND destination.latitude BETWEEN lat1 and lat2 
    HAVING distance < dist
GROUP BY
    destination.id  
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I did try that, but it throws the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT( photos.pid ), CHAR(8) ) ) ) AS photo, destination.id, desti' at line 2

Comment: If I take my original code and add a DISTINCT and then a GROUP BY destination.id before the ORDER BY statement, it throws an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY destination.id ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50; END' at line 20

Comment: Try it without the distinct and It might not even be needed with the group by destination.id, might not be able to use it inside the other functions.  In any case distance queries can be a pain, you might have to do it in 2 procedures

Comment: It is looking more and more like I am going to have to do this in 2 procedures, I appreciate the help. Performance is already taking a major hit, the only other option I can think of is, I can filter through the results using PHP ( since that is what I am using ) and remove the duplicates from the results array. Otherwise, I have to perform a separate query on each individual result, which would not even make any sense. Performance would be destroyed.